# ASP.NET Security: Deny Anonymous access to login page

Tags: asp.net, security, web-config, anonymous

I'm looking to deny all anonymous access to my login page and only allow people who are in a certain role to be able to view the page or anything under that directory. Is this possible? I have tried to implement this in the web.config but had no joy :(

thanks

Comment: how do you know the user's role until the user logs in?

Comment: I'm looking to use the windows login to check their roles when viewing the page. Is this possible? Is it even the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

This would only be possible in an intranet application where your users would be authenticated against Active directory. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Otherwise, how would users log in if they don't have access to the login page?

I would rather implement access control on the actual content pages, or do an additional check when users attempt to log in and let them know that they need to be in a certain role in order to log into the system successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can...assuming that your clients are all running Windows workstations that are in the same AD domain as your IIS webservers and are using Internet Explorer (so, intranet only and not over the Internet). You want to configure IIS to only accept Integrated Windows Authentication, which will force the client workstations to use Kerberos to supply authentication information to IIS. Here's [a how-to from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324274) on how to configure this.

Answer (score 0):

In **web.config**:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <location path="MyLoginPage.aspx"> 
         <system.web>
            <authorization>
               <deny users="?"/>
            </authorization>
         </system.web>
      </location>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The special keyword `?` means **anonymous users**; which is documented in [the element schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aeskccd.aspx):

> **Attribute**: users
>
> A comma-separated list of user names that are denied access to the resource.
>   A question mark (?) denies anonymous users and an asterisk (*) indicates that all user accounts are denied access.

Basically this is the Microsoft long-winded way of saying:

- **Location:** MyLoginPage.aspx
- **Deny:** anonymous

This means that someone will have to be authenticated using a mechanism other than **Form**; such as **Integrated** (aka Kerberos, Windows) authentication, or with **Basic** authentication. You won't be able to use **Forms Authentication**, because they won't be able to reach the login page to login.